# Can Excel use a "computed" array for Vlookup?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

In the screen capture below, what text would replace the red text to allow ranges from `G` and `H` to be calculated in the `VLOOKUP`?

I tried various uses of Address and concatenates but can not find a solution.

[image: Screenshot]

See [the source of this question](/revisions/fee2d386-013d-48ce-9eb0-24d080925dad/view-source) for a partial (copy & pastable) text
version of the above spreadsheet.

Comment: We actually prefer that spreadsheet data be posted as text, as was done [here](//superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](//superuser.com/q/892744/150988); use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table) site if you want.  (I used it when I created the textual table I hid in your question.)  See [Please don’t post images of text.](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408) for reasons.  (Although I’ll admit that the color coding helps a little.)  It’s also helpful to post the actual values you hope to get, so people can sanity-check their attempted solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is `INDIRECT()`. 
This returns a reference specified by a string. 
For example,
`INDIRECT("B2")` is equivalent to a reference to the cell `B2`,
and `INDIRECT("B2:C4")` is equivalent to a reference to the range `B2:C4`.

Obviously,
you need to get the text string values from `G2:H11` down into `D18:D32`. 
This is easy;
just use `VLOOKUP(A18, A$2:H$11, 7)` and `VLOOKUP(A18, A$2:H$11, 8)`. 
Using these building blocks, we get this formula for `D18`:

```
=VLOOKUP(B18, INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(A18, A$2:H$11, 7) & ":" & VLOOKUP(A18, A$2:H$11, 8)), 2)
```

in which we combine the “first cell” value (from Column `G`, a.k.a. column 7)
and the “last cell” value (from Column `H`, a.k.a. column 8)
with a colon (`:`), using the `&` string concatenate operator. 
Then use `INDIRECT()` to turn strings like `B2:C4` into searchable ranges. 
Then drag/fill `D18` down.

[image: spreadsheet]

The commission% for bob comes up as `#N/A` because his dates are wrong:
`B5` and `B6` are in 2017, but `B25:B27` are in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

You have two criteria, so it is simpler if you learn to use `INDEX MATCH` instead.

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$11,
       MATCH(1, (A18 = $A$2:$A$11) * (B18 < $B$2:$B$11), 0)
 )
```

and remember to press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert this array formula.

---

`$C$2:$C$11` is your Commission column

`MATCH(1, ..., 0)` is only looking where both the conditions within is true.

`A18 = $A$2:$A$11` is looking for matching Name

`B18 < $B$2:$B$11` is looking for Date earlier than referenced Date

Comment: Did you try your formula?  It works only on Rows 23 and 31, where the dates match exactly.

Comment: @Scott After reading the question again, I realized it was supposed to be `<` instead of `=`. Thanks!